# \newcommand of tcbitemize in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How to newcommand the number of rows and columns of tcbitemize in tcolorbox?

```
\newcommand{\boxdivide}[2][]
{\begin{tcbitemize}
[raster columns=#1,raster rows=#2,
    raster every    box/.style={colframe=white,colback=white},
    raster left skip=0pt,raster right skip=0pt,raster column 
    skip=0pt,raster before skip=0pt,raster after skip=0pt]} 
{\end{tcbitemize}}
```

gives an error.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a short, but compilable minimal reproducible example.